# User interaction is still available to the clipped portion of a View - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

`.clipped()` Modifier is clipping the child to the bounds of its parent. But the user interaction of the child is still enabled in the clipped portion. It seems like the modifier simply hides the outside portion. Is there any way to disable user interaction with the hidden portion of the view?

My code is given below,

```
struct ClippingCheckView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green.opacity(0.8))
            }
            .frame(width: 250, height: 150, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: -50, y: -50)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        .clipped()
        .background(Color.red.opacity(0.7))
        .onTapGesture {
            print("RED View Tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.clipped` is only for drawing, to limit tap handling we should use `.contentShape`, like

```
    .clipped()
    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.7))
    .contentShape(Rectangle())            // << here !!
    .onTapGesture {
        print("RED View Tapped")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it limits the area but still, some of the outside areas are tappable. Is there any way to give a custom frame to that content shape to match the parent's dimension?

Comment: I assume your tap overlaps visible area, tap is a spot not a dot.